# QR factorization of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a $QR$ factorization of a matrix $A$, given that $A$ is orthogonal.

So we know that the QR factorization means that *for a given $m \times n $ matrix $A$ with linearly independent columns, there exists a factorization $QR$ such that $Q$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with orthonormal columns and $R$ is an invertible upper triangular matrix.*

I don't really know what extra insight the fact that $A$ is orthogonal provides us here. We now know that $A$ is a square matrix, which means that $Q$ is also a square matrix and as such, $Q$ is also an orthogonal matrix.

But I don't see how this can give us a generalised $QR$ factorization in this case, can anyone provide a hint?

Comment: To paraphrase Ghandi: 'be the QR-decomposition you want to see in this world'. Remember that the identity matrix also 'counts' as an invertible upper triangular matrix

Comment: @Vincent So $R=I$ and $Q=A$ would be the QR factorisation they want?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds good enough to me!

Answer (score 1):

$A = QR$
Since $Q$ is calculated by computing the orthogonal basis for $A$, $Q = A$ in the case that $A$ is already orthogonal.
To find $R$, we can rearrange the equality to be $Q^{-1}$$A = R$.
Recall $Q = A$, so we substitute to find that $A^{-1}$$A$ $=$ $R$ $=$ $I$
Since $A$ is orthogonal, its inverse is equal to its transpose and we have $A^{T}$$A$ $=$ $R$ $=$ $I$.
Thus, when $A$ is orthogonal, its $QR$ factorization is $A = IA$

Comment: You mean $AI_n$.